# OpcUA client connection without a certificate using eclipse milo

Tags: eclipse, opc-ua, milo

Is it possible to have a OPCUA client connect to server without certificate using eclipse milo java sdk? When I try to that I get an exception saying that the certificateBytes can not be null.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible... are you sure you're connecting to an endpoint with security disabled? (`SecurityPolicy.NONE`).

Comment: Before connecting I am checking if the endpoint's SecurityPolicyUri is equal to that of SecurityPolicy.None.getSecurityPolicyUri()

Comment: Can you post some code? I configured one of the examples so that it doesn't set a certificate or keyPair when building the config and it has no issue connecting...

Comment: Thanks for trying it out Kevin. Will it be possible for you to share the sample example and the way you configured it?

Comment: In `ClientExampleRunner` I just commented out the `setCertificate` and `setKeyPair` calls on the config builder.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem was with the OpcUa server that I was running.  It was running without a certificate and that was causing the issue.